# Lisp Interpreter in a C++ Program

Tags: c++, lisp

I'm not sure I'm phrasing this right, but I'm pretty sure I'm looking for a LISP interpreter I can put in my C++ program.

The ideal situation I'm imagining is a function or something to which I can pass either a string, file, or filename containing the LISP code and then use the output from the LISP code in other parts.

To put it in terms of `(print (eval (read)))`, I want `read` to be something I input to be what's read, and a string or something I can parse from print.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is also [ECL](http://ecls.sourceforge.net/) ("Embeddable Common Lisp"). It has the advantage, that it provides the full Common Lisp standard. Unfortunately, the [documentation with respect to embedding](http://ecls.sourceforge.net/new-manual/ch23.html) is... well... a little bit scarce.

I never used it myself, so I cannot really tell, whether this would actually be an easy thing to embed into your application. IMHO, the Guile interpreter would be a reasonable choice.

Another embeddable Lisp is [Rep](http://librep.sourceforge.net/), which is, for example, the extension language used by the Sawfish window manager. It started as Emacs lisp clone, but became something different over time, and is nowadays closer to Scheme.

Comment: Regarding examples using ECL, there's this example using gcc https://gist.github.com/vwood/662109 and I ported it to VS2012 https://github.com/fabriceleal/ecl-win-vs11-example

Answer (score 7):

If you're interested in Common Lisp, there's [ECL](http://ecls.sourceforge.net/).

From the [FAQ](http://ecls.wikispaces.com/FAQ):

> 2.1 What does this "embedding" stuff mean?
>
> ECL is a full fledge
>   implementation of the Common-Lisp
>   language. However, due to the way it
>   is implemented, the implementation can
>   be used as an extensibility language
>   for your own application, much like
>   Guile works for the Scheme language.
>   By a rather simple set of functions,
>   you can parse, compile and execute
>   Common-Lisp forms, and using the
>   Foreign Function Interface (FFI), you
>   can add new functions to Common-Lisp
>   which suit your Domain-Specific
>   Language.

And:

> 2.2 How do I embed ECL into my application?
>
> You have to use the ECL library, which
>   is called libecl.so, libecl.dyld or
>   ecl.dll, depending on your operating
>   system (Unix, Mac OSX or Windows). The
>   program ecl-config will provide you
>   with the flags you have to pass to the
>   C/C++ compiler and to the linker,
>   using either ecl-config --cflags or
>   ecl-config --ldflags, respectively.
>   Regarding your program, apart from
>   linking against the ECL library, you
>   have to call the proper initialization
>   routine, cl_boot(), so that ECL sets
>   up the appropiate internal structures.
>   After calling this routine, you will
>   be able to run lisp code and create or
>   manipulate lisp data

.

Answer (score 3):

It's not Lisp, but [Guile](http://www.gnu.org/s/guile/) is the GNU cross platform scripting language, and is an interpreter/compiler for Scheme, which is pretty close to Lisp.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GNU Guile](http://www.gnu.org/s/guile/), which is a Scheme interpreter specifically designed to be easily embeddable in C/C++ programs.

Answer (score 0):

Try anything that comes up under this search: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=embedded+lisp

It turns out that a lot of people have wanted to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For something even more embeddable than Guile, there's also [Chibi](http://code.google.com/p/chibi-scheme/).

(I <3 Guile BTW, so this answer isn't trying to take away from that---it just offers another option.)